# ATI driver on my Fedora notebook working, but with weird abstract color bugs

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, fedora, amd-catalyst

I'm running Fedora 15 64-bit on a HP Pavilion dv7. I've installed [this driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) (AMD Catalyst™ 11.8 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver), and here's a screenshot of the info window in CCC:

[image]

My uname:

> Linux ninja 2.6.40.3-0.fc15.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 16 04:10:59 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here's a screenshot depicting my problem:

[image]

The top bar is completely messed up in abstract colors, and the icons are no better. This does however seem to be the only problem.

If anyone has any suggestions for fixing this I'd appreciate hearing it! :-)

Comment: Does this persist after you reboot your computer?

Comment: Yes - [This text is for padding purposes to allow me to commit the comment]

Comment: Well actually it seems the scrambled up icons (volume, battery) are now displaying correctly, but still on a yellow/blue/purple/red background